# Why enum values for some sensors are missing from <android/sensor.h>? Is it safe to use them?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, sensors

It seems that enum values for some sensors are missing from `<android/sensor.h>`.

The file defines following enum:

```
/*
 * Sensor types
 * (keep in sync with hardware/sensor.h)
 */

enum {
    ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER      = 1,
    ASENSOR_TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD     = 2,
    ASENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE          = 4,
    ASENSOR_TYPE_LIGHT              = 5,
    ASENSOR_TYPE_PROXIMITY          = 8
};
```

The comment says that this enum is synced with `<hardware/sensor.h>` (which is not exposed, it's a part of android source).

But in the `<hardware/sensor.h>` I've found [values](http://source.android.com/devices/halref/sensors_8h.html) for many more useful sensors like pressure, temperature and humidity ones:

```
#define SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER         (1) 
#define SENSOR_TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_FIELD     (2) 
#define SENSOR_TYPE_ORIENTATION           (3)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE             (4)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_LIGHT                 (5)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_PRESSURE              (6)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_TEMPERATURE           (7)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_PROXIMITY             (8)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY               (9)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION   (10)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR       (11)
#define SENSOR_TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY     (12)
// ...
#define SENSOR_TYPE_HEART_BEAT            (31)
```

**Why some sensors are not listed in the `<android/sensor.h>`? It it safe and portable to use them?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment it is absolutely safe to use constants from `<hardware/sensor.h>` since [`SensorManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1bf797857e025e8a71db86fb9e79765a767ec1eb/libs/gui/SensorManager.cpp#40) populates its internal sensor list with data from system-wide `ISensorServer` without any remapping of type values. And `ISensorServer` uses `<hardware/sensor.h>` constants.

I guess NDK API exposes constrained type set just because it was not updated for a while.

P.S. Of course things will be broken if some kind of mapping arise in future, but IMO AOSP will keep it unchanged.