# Android NDK Linear Acceleration not available

Tags: android-ndk, accelerometer, sensors

I am trying to write most of my code purely using the android NDK and am currently at reading out the accelerations from the sensor. In Android java you were able to choose between Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. According to the [Android NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___sensor.html#gga7ff5f2dff38e7639981794c43dc9167ba3665ff44389ff1ef84d1f60cede4c19a) enumerations, there should also be a linear acceleration but when i navigate by hand to sensor.h, no such enumeration exists. Did they remove it?

As info, i am currently on NDK Version 13.1.3345770

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: NDK header just misses that constant. It was never added to it. Anyway, you may declare it by yourself. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38894435/2878070).